# Why is Hanuman considered as a partial avatara of Lord Shiva as opposed to a full avatara?

Tags: shiva, hanuman

HanumAn is said to be an ansha avatar of Lord Shiva. With an ansha avatar being defined as a partial avatar. Where is the proof of HanumAn being a ansha avatar from the hindu scriptures?

Comment: No I am specically looking for proof that he is an ANSHA avatar.

Comment: You can edit the question a lil bit. I guess ur main inquiry is - "Why is Hanuman considered as a partial avatara of Lord Shiva as opposed to a full avatara?" Since, u are not asking whether he is an avatara or not (which u already know to be the case) it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not good in choosing the correct words. How can I now remove the duplicate marking?

Comment: There are already 2 reopen votes for the question. So, 3 more reopen votes are required to remove that duplicate marking from the question.

Comment: @UdayKrishna  So there is no scriptual basis that he is an partial avatar?

Answer (score 3):

##### There are multiple references in the Paurāṇika Literature that refers to Hanumān as "Śiva's (Rudra's) part" i.e. Rudra-'aṃśa'.

Some of those references are -

1. Skanda Purāṇa
   (i): SkP 5.2.79.6.b
    (ii). SkP 5.3.84.6.a
2. Brahmavaivarta Purāṇa: BP 4.62.63
3. Nāradīya Purāṇa: NP 1.79.353

---

#### 1.  Skanda Purāṇa :

- In two different Chapters, Skanda Purāṇa (Book 5 - Āvantya-khaṇḍa) explicitly refers to Hanumān as an '*aṃśa*' (i.e., part) of Rudra.

> ##### (i).  Section 2 - Caturaśīti-liṅga-māhātmya
>
> [Verse 5.2.79.6](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/skanda-purana-sanskrit/d/doc786134.html)
>
> चिरं जीवतु दीर्घायुर्वानरो हनुमान्सदा । अंजनीगर्भसंभूतो **रुद्रांशो**
> हि धरातले ॥ ६ ॥
>
> ciraṃ jīvatu dīrghāyurvānaro hanumānsadā | aṃjanīgarbhasaṃbhūto
> **rudrāṃśo** hi dharātale || 6 ||
>
> > 6. May the monkey Hanumān be long-lived. **He is a part of Rudra** on the
> >    surface of the earth. He is born in the womb of Añjanā.
>
> [Chapter 79](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc425723.html) - Hanumatkeśvara, Caturaśīti-liṅga-māhātmya

AND

> ##### (ii). Section 3 - Revā-khaṇḍa
>
> [Verse 5.3.84.5-6](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/skanda-purana-sanskrit/d/doc790072.html)
>
> > Īśvara said:
>
> तस्मिन्प्रशासति ततो राज्यं निहतकण्टकम् । कृतकार्योऽथ
> हनुमान्कैलासमगात्पुरा ॥ ५ ॥
>  ततो नन्दी प्रतीहारो **रुद्रांशमपि** तं
> कपिम् । न च संगमयामास रुद्रेणाघौघहारिणा ॥ ६ ॥
>
> > 5. & 6. Hanumān who had completed his task went to Kailāsa. Nandin, the
> >    doorkeeper, did not allow the monkey, **though he was a part of Rudra,**
> >    to meet Rudra, the destroyer of a heap of sins.
>
> [Chapter 84](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc425813.html) - Kapi and Other Tīrthas

---

#### 2. Brahmavaivarta Purāṇa:

- This reference is found in the Śrī-Kṛṣṇa-janma Khaṇḍaḥ

> ##### [Chapter 62](https://archive.org/details/brahma-vaivarta-purana-all-four-kandas-english-translation/page/438/mode/2up) - The Life Story of Rāma
>
> हनुमान्पययौ लङ्कां सीतान्वेषणहेतवे ।
>  रामादधीतसंदेशो ययौ
> **रुद्रकलोद्भवः** ॥ [६३](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%AA_(%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%9C%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83)/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A6%E0%A5%AC%E0%A5%A8) ॥
>
> > Hanumān who was born of the **aṃśa of Rudra** receiving the message from
> > Rāma traveled to Lanka in search of Sītā
>
> English Translation by Shanti Lal Nagar

---

#### 3. Nāradīya Purāṇa

- This is found in Chapter 79 - Part 1 of the Nāradīya Purāṇa

> ##### [Chapter 79](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.21516/page/n229/mode/2up) - Hanumaccaritraṃ
>
> प्रत्यक्षं मम विप्रेंद्र हनुमान्हर्षमागगतः ॥ ७९-३५२ ॥ समस्तभूषासु
> षेतांगः स्वदीप्तिर्मदीकृतदेवदीप्तिः ।। प्रसन्नमूर्तिस्तरुणः
> **शिवांशः** संभावयामास समस्तदेवान् ॥ ७९-३५३ ॥
>
> Hanumān was highly pleased this has been seen by me. Hanumān is well
> bedecked in all ornaments. He has made the luster of gods dim by his
> excellent luster. He has a delighted form, he is young. **Hanumān is a part
> of Śiva.** He honored all the gods.

---

So,

##### `Question - Why is Hanuman considered as a partial avatara of Lord Shiva as opposed to a full avatara?`

Ans - Because the above mentioned scriptures say so.

Answer (score 2):

God Hanuman is called Shambhu-putra (God Shiva's son) [Ref: Parashara Samhita 54.8 translated by Dr Annadanam Sasthry].

Of course, this also means He was an 'ansha' (part) of God Shiva.